# Import new characters into a pretrained deep learning based OCR model

Tags: deep-learning, ocr

Now I have a pre-trained deep learning based OCR model but in my real applications there exist several characters not included in the dictionary of my pre-trained model.  A small dataset mainly consisting of those new characters is also available.  I want the model to learn to recognize new characters without weakening its ability to identify characters in the original dictionary. 
  However, when I append those new characters onto the model's classification layer and finetune the weights on my dataset, the model performs poorly due to the imbalance in the class distribution of my dataset.  Is there any way to effectively import these new characters into my pre-trained model?